# angularjs $http on IE

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

I have been testing my angularjs application on mozila and chrome and all was ok
when i moved to ie 11 and started testing i notice all my $http request doestnt work 
and all my request to the server that fetches json object fails 
i add this in the header `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">`
but still no luck 
very strange behavior 
I didn't check all the functionality but i am guessing there is more problems 
any idea why ? 
The IE console doesnt say anything

Comment: What is the error message of the failed request? Maybe you show the code making the failed request. Some details would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Turns out IE doesn't know to work with window.location.origin unlike 
the others browsers i was using it to build the url to send the http request  - Strange but i finally found it